# Creating Protocol/Delegate in Monotouch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

I'm a bit confused with how to create a custom protocol/delegate type in Monotouch.

The obj-c equivalent is

```
@protocol CellController
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
   @optional
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end
```

Does the implementation have to be an abstract class, an interface or what?

I'm sure its not complicated, I just can't get my head around it. A code example would be helpful, but getting pointed in the right direction will still be extremely helpful

Cheers

R

Comment: I believe so, I need to define cellcontroller as a delegate type. Those methods are just an example. If I want to create a uitableview delegate as you correctly say I can inherit from uitableviewdelegate

Comment: Will this delegate type you are trying to create be used as a delegate object on an already existing iOS object, or a new, custom object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was creating an interface and using that :)